# how to obtain documents of record in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

```
Meteor.publish('get',function(){
        return clases.find();
    });

Meteor.subscribe('get');
```

obtain documents of my publicatons

```
var clases1=clases.find();

_.forEach(clases1, function(claseaux){
claseaux2.name
});
```

My collection class has an attribute called name, but I can not access it like `clasea.name`

Comment: `claseaux2` will be undefined. Leave off the "2".

Answer (score 1):

`Collection.find` returns a MiniMongo cursor, not a JS array.

You could use `Cursor.forEach` to iterate over the cursor, once the initial set of documents have been sent to the client after the subscription is ready :

```
Meteor.subscribe("get", function(){
  clases.find().forEach(function(claseaux){
    console.log(claseaux.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: never enters the foreach, but all documents are there

Comment: changed `Collection.fetch` to `Collection.find` in the answer.